# How to use "Automate" Android App to have newly taken photo is saved into DCIM/whatever folder not DCIM/Camera folder?

Tags: applications, camera

I've installed "Automate" Android App which I thought that I can use it easily.
But it turned out I don't understand at all on how to use it.

I've read a simple tutorial on [how to create "Hello World"](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-automate-tasks-and-workflows-on-android-with-the-automate-app/) with this app, but I can't find any where else a tutorial on how to do the things I want with this app.

I've read the ["Automate" documentation](https://llamalab.com/automate/doc/index.html), but I still don't understand at all.

My Android Camera phone will directly put the taken photo into DCIM/Camera folder. 
 So what I want is :

- A. Either "automate" the newly taken photo into DCIM/whatever folder
- B. Or "automate" to move the newly taken photo from DCIM/Camera folder into DCIM/whatever folder.

I've read in this site a question which is similar to mine : 
[How can I save taken photos and recorded videos out of DCIM folder?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/33570/how-can-i-save-taken-photos-and-recorded-videos-out-of-dcim-folder)
But the question is about external-sd card and the answer is using Tasker App.

So if it's possible to do it with Automate App, I wonder how do I do it.
Any kind of respond would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advanced.

---

Comment: Please when writing an answer do it in the answers section, not inside the question itself. You are allowed to answer your own questions.

Comment: @Robert, I am sorry... I thought if it's still not solved yet then it's still a question, not the answer. Anyway I will move it as the answer although actually it's still my same question.

Answer (score 0):

Both the [Camera](https://llamalab.com/automate/doc/block/camera_capture.html) and [Take picture](https://llamalab.com/automate/doc/block/take_picture.html) blocks has a *Destination path* input argument field, click it and choose directory and filename where the picture will be saved.

Comment: Hi... thank you for the answer, ballzak. I've tried it but still no luck. If you don't mind please have a look on my edited question. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did:
Create a new Flow Beginning. 
[image]
Inside the Flow Beginning, I just fill the Title and let the rest at default.

---

Then I add the "Camera" block and connect it with the "Flow Beginning"
[image]

---

Inside the "Camera" I check the "Show window directly if possible" and the rest at default.
[image]

---

[image]

After I start the Flow, the Camera App launch, so I shot one photo, then check the DCIM folder.

---

Inside the DCIM folder, there is "Automate" folder which I think it was automatically created when I run the Flow.
[image]

But the photo I took is still inside the DCIM/Camera folder. The DCIM/Automate folder is empty.

---

So, within the Camera block, I change the Destination Path to DCIM/Automate folder 
[image]

I start the Flow, take one picture, then check the DCIM folder.
No luck. The photo is still saved into DCIM/Camera folder. The DCIM/Automate folder still empty.

---

Next try, I remove the "Camera" block, then put the "Take Picture" block.
Inside the "Take Picture" block, I put the Path Destination to DCIM/Automate folder. Once I start the Flow, the Camera App didn't launch, but funny thing is when I check the DCIM/Automate folder, the picture is there. So, it seems the "Take Picture" block run the Camera App in the background.

---

Next try, I have the flow like this : Flow beginning ---> Camera (with DCIM/Automate folder as the destination path) ---> Take Picture (also with DCIM/Automate folder as the destination path). Then I start the flow and take a picture. No luck. The photo is still saved to DCIM/Camera folder not to DCIM/Automate folder).

---

I don't know what else to do.
I hope someone can enlighten me :).

Comment: The default Camera app on your device, Samsung maybe, probably doesn't support the Android standard of supplying a destination file. The Take picture block doesn't rely on the Camera app, so it has no such problem.

Comment: Oh I see. Thank you balzak for your explanation.